# Start a new git repo from a current branch

Tags: git

In playing with my webapp, I added files containing passwords to my git repo.  I've since removed them, but I'd like to start a new git repo that doesn't have the commits when the passwords were included (I've changed the passwords, just like to start anew).

Is there someway I can grab a git repo without grabbing all the history? Or should I just copy the folder and start a new git repo in the copied folder?  How would I start a new git repo, just remove the `.git` folder and then rerun `git init`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, if you know you don't want any of the history just delete the .git folder and  rerun `git init`. Another option, if you would like to keep your history, is to follow [this](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) excellent Github guide on removing sensitive data.

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the `.git` directory from your working copy is certainly the easiest solution.  If you are interested in more complex solutions, read on:

You can create a "shallow clone" of a repository using the `-d` (`--depth`) option to `git clone`.  For example:

```
git clone --depth 1 file:///path/to/your/repo
```

You need to use a `file://` in this case because `git` will ignore the `-d` option when you use a simple path.

If you would rather preserve the change history, you can rewrite your repository to remove the files containing passwords.  Take a look at `git filter-branch`, and in particular the section "Removing a file from every commit" in [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html).